# Why cant I solve for t here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

This is one of those cup of coffee questions. The room temperature is $20$ degrees.

$T = $ Temperature of Coffee, $t=$ time

How long until the coffee cools to room temperature if
$$T=20+80e^{-kt}$$
I have already found that $k=\frac{1}{2}\ln{\frac{8}{7}}$.

How to isolate $t$ ?
$$20=20 + 80e^{-kt}$$

Comment: So, the value $20$ is the asymptote, the temperature gets very close to $20$ but never reaches exactly $20$.

Comment: Tjis is apparently what I need to do (see page 4)http://www2.fiu.edu/~aladrog/ModelingFirstOrderEq.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from below:$$\begin{align} & 20=20 + 80e^{-kt} \\ \implies & 80e^{-kt}=0  \\ \implies & e^{-kt}=0 \\ \implies & e^{kt} \to \infty \\ \implies & t \to \infty\end{align}$$
There is no unique solution to this equation. What you can conclude at most is that $t \to \infty$ since $k=\frac{1}{20}\ln \frac{8}{7}>0$.

Comment: That makes sense. It turns out I need to work out when it gets very close to room temperature and then make sense of it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Logarithms:

$$T=20+80e^{-kt}\implies e^{kt}=\frac{80}{T-20}\implies kt=\log\frac{80}{T-20}\implies t=\frac1k\cdot\log\frac{80}{T-20}$$

Of course, the above is defined **only** for $\;T>20\;$ , so in your case there wouldn't be any solutions.

Comment: I think it should be $T-20$. You have messed up between $t$ and $T$.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Thanks, of course you're right. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

$$20=20+80e^{-\text{k}t}\Longleftrightarrow\ln\left(\frac{20-20}{80}\right)=-\text{k}t$$

But know we notice that $\frac{20-20}{80}=0$ and:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\ln(x)\to-\infty$$

So, there are no solutions (as a finite number) but when $\text{k}>0$, then $t\to\infty$

Answer (score 0):

With your model, the coffee actually *never* cools down to room temperature, because the equation
$$
20=20+80e^{-kt}
$$
is equivalent to the equation
$$
0=e^{-kt}.
$$
But because $e^x>0$ for all real numbers $x$, there is no $t$ that satisfies the equation above.